# applicationWillEnterForeground never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hey there, I'm trying Multitasking in the Simulator (I only have a 2nd gen iPod and an iPad) and I'm still having some problems. My testing methods look like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
 NSLog(@"Entering %s",__FUNCTION__);

 if (enteredFromBackground) {
  NSLog(@"Entering from Background");
  enteredFromBackground = NO;
 }
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
 NSLog(@"Entering %s",__FUNCTION__);

 enteredFromBackground = YES;
}
```

Unforntunately, I'm not seeing the NSLog from applicationWillEnterForeground, that's why I added the line to show me something in applicationDidBecomeActive.
All I get is the

```
2010-11-20 15:58:12.796 iBeat[45997:207] Entering -[AppDelegate_Shared applicationDidEnterBackground:]
2010-11-20 15:58:18.160 iBeat[45997:207] Entering -[AppDelegate_Shared applicationDidBecomeActive:]
```

Comment: The accepted answer is not my scenario and I still have this problem. I have an iOS app which doesn't adopt scenes. In iOS 16.2 simulator, applicationWillEnterForeground is never invoked. 
It's counterpart, applicationWillEnterBackground is invoked consistently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found my problem!
Since I have a universal Application, I have an Appdelegate_Shared, an Appdelegate_iPhone, and an Appdelegate_iPad. 
I had an empty implementation of "applicationWillEnterForeground" in the two subclasses but didn't call super!

And then I wondered why the method in Appdelegate_Shared never got called o.O

Answer (score 12):

After having this problem in iOS 13, I found out that I was waiting for `applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)` to be called instead of `sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene)`.

For more information, read this answer:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498306/7969193)

Comment: I have an iOS app which doesn't adopt scenes. But still, appWillEnterForeground(_:) was never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023:

1. Remove scene manifest completely from `Info.plist`.
2. Add `@UIApplicationMain` right before your `AppDelegate` declaration.
3. Initialize `UIWindow` and set it to `window` property in `AppDelegate`

```swift
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    // other code...
}
```

At least, it's helped me. Cheers.

P.S. Swift 5.9, Xcode 15.0.1, Device Target iOS 17.0;

Comment: This is going in the wrong direction. You should be using scenes, not removing them.

Comment: @HangarRash Well, it sounds obviously correct what you've said, but all I did is just follow Apple's [Placing Objects and Handling 3D Interaction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arkit_in_ios/environmental_analysis/placing_objects_and_handling_3d_interaction) step by step to get better understanding how it works talking about interacting with objects in ARKit. And at the same time just decided to leave a reply here for the question. But yeah, I agree with you.