# Navigate to main app after successful signup, should I use SceneDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to mobile development using Xcode (xcode 11.4 with Swift 4), and am currently learning how to create an authentication page that navigates to `MainViewController` on success.

My story board sketch looks like this:[image]

Where the top row is the `LoginViewController` segueing into `ConfirmationViewController`. The bottom row is the `MainViewController` of the app, accessible after the user has created an account.

In my `SceneDelegate.swift`, I set the entry point to be `LoginViewController` if user is not signed in, otherwise the entry point is `MainViewController`. Code snippet here:

```
    var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    // initialize application window and scenes
    self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let errorViewController   = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ErrorPage")
    let tabViewController     = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tab"  )
    let signUpController      = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")

    // initialize storyboard entry point
    AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
            if let userState = userState {

            print("userState: \(userState)")

            switch (userState) {
                case .guest:
                    print("user is in guest mode.")
                    self.window?.rootViewController = signUpController
                case .signedOut:
                    print("user signed out")
                    self.window?.rootViewController = signUpController
                case .signedIn:
                    print("user is signed in")
                    self.window?.rootViewController = tabViewController
                case .signedOutUserPoolsTokenInvalid:
                    print("need to login again.")
                    self.window?.rootViewController = signUpController
                case .signedOutFederatedTokensInvalid:
                    print("user logged in via federation, but currently needs new tokens")
                    self.window?.rootViewController = signUpController
                default:
                    print("unsupported")
            }

            } else if let error = error {
            print("error: AWSMobileClient failed to load user \(error)")
            self.window?.rootViewController = errorViewController
        }
    }
}
```

This works as intended. Now in my `ConfirmationViewController` I need to have some logic that directs the user to the main app `MainViewController` on successful confirmation

```
    @IBAction func onPressConfirmEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
// @use: on confirmation success, navigate to application main
// @error: show error in the same page and ask person to try again

}
```

}

The problem is I'm not sure what is the "right" way to do this. The way Xcode has setup the project appears very specific, and there is "one right way." Please elucidate.

Comment: There is a preferred way to do things, but never only one right way. Even Apple, who seem to favor all apps to made using a Xerox machine are flexible if you are confident in your logic. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444248/how-i-can-implement-login-logout-navigation-using-userdefaults-in-swift for some ideas on how to use the recently updated SceneDelegate structure.

Comment: @AbandonedCart yeah that example was very helpful, and I implemented the part in SceneDelegate. The issue is what to do after the user *initially* signs up. The user should be redirected from the confirm-email page to the main app. This is the part where I am soft on. Because the confirm email logic is no in SceneDelegate, it is in something like `ConfirmEmailViewContorller.swift`. And there is no reference to `scene: UIScene` there. Which is needed if we want to set something like `self.window?.rootViewController = mainAppVC`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the question or sample code really clarified that, but hopefully your comment will help someone to provide you with a better answer. Unfortunately, I am primarily an Android developer and do not have a definitive answer "off the cuff."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Segue between your ConfirmationViewController and your MainViewController in the storyboard and then you can use:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: self).
```

Or you can use:

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you want to go back to the root view controller

```
_ = navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code part with the inbuilt code formatting tool.

Comment: Is segue the right construct? The ones I create leads to a a modal pop-over, and allow the user to navigate back. In this case I'm looking for a transition that is one directional.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry by my english (I'm trying to learn it).

Recently I've implemented AWS login in a SwiftUI project. And following what Apple recommends (don't make process during app launch), the unique solution that I've founded was make my app ever open login screen first without any elements - all elements with opacity zero.

Then after the login screen has been displayed, I check the AWS status to show home or stay at login screen.

I hope help you (I've tried :P ).